# Find a basis for a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve for a basis for this subspace $W$?

$W = \{ \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \in F[x] | \sum_{i=0}^k a_i =0 \text{ and } \sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i =0  \}$, where $n$ is an integer such that $n=2k \geq 4$. $F$ is a field.

Thanks. :D

Comment: ops sorry. that was a mistake. but i edited it already :D @egreg

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $f\colon V\to F^2$ defined by
$$
f(a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum\limits_{0\le i\le k}a_i
\\[5px]
\sum\limits_{k+1\le i\le n}a_i
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $V$ is the vector subspace of $F[x]$ consisting of polynomials of degree at most $n$.

Then it should be clear that $f$ is linear and surjective; moreover $W=\ker f$, so
$$
\dim W=(n+1)-2=n-1
$$
What about a basis? If a polynomial belongs to $W$, then $a_k$ is determined by $a_0,\dots,a_{k-1}$ and $a_n$ is determined by $a_{k+1},\dots, a_{n-1}$.

The matrix of the linear map with respect to the basis $\{1,x,\dots,x^n\}$ is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
where the first block is $2\times(k+1)$ and the second block is $2\times(n-k)$.

Thus the equations are
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0=-a_1-a_2-\dots-a_k\\
a_{k+1}=-a_{k+2}-\dots-a_n
\end{cases}
$$
so a basis of $W=\ker f$ is given by
$$
\{1-x,1-x^2,\dots,1-x^k,x^{k+1}-x^{k+2},\dots,x^{k+1}-x^n\}
$$

Comment: the basis is in terms of $a_i's$? not polynomial?

Comment: @mogs What are you saying? Of course the basis should be a set of polynomials.